# XMLデータベースを繋ぐRESTのwebサービスの開発について（JAVA）

Tags: java, xml, rest, soap

どうか、お知恵をお貸しください！１週間ほどまずは自力でやってみようと本やネットを見ながら挑戦して見ましたが、サッパリだったのでここで質問させてください。

初めてプログラミングをします。
XMLデータベースから情報をxmlで取得し、XQueryで返すREST Webサービスを作らなければなりません。

内容：
XMLデータベース（添付画像＞飛行機の名前、製造年月日、画像、説明文など各飛行機につき１０項目がXMLで記載されている）
このデータを参照するための REST WebサービスをJavaで書きたい。

**XMLデータベース**

[image: XMLデータベースの内容]

ゴールとしてはサーバー上で
例：製造年月日が新しい順に並べ替えたい
　　→　その際にこのデータベースからデータを参照
　　→　並び替えられた写真などのデータが表示される

今回、開発に際し揃えたソフト：
Tomcat 8.0  localhost
Jersey 2.0
Eclipse 4.4 (Luna PHPなどの入ったpackage)
JAVA 1.8
JDK 8

全くの初心者のため、本や
YoutubeやWebseiteのTutorial (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html , http://javabrains.koushik.org/tutorials/javaee_jaxrs/Introduction.html , インストールに際し、個別に各ソフトのインストールと起動方法のページ)

流れとしてはEclipse上で
WEb serviceのプログラミングを書く
@pathなどの書いてあるページと、それに呼応するjavaのページを下記要領で作成

1. dynamic web projectを作る
2. JARsをすべてコピーして入れ
3. Javaで 新しいpackageを作る
4. javaclassを作る
5. web.xml を作る

Webクライアントのページ作成

もしくは、今回の場合、webクライント側だけでもいいのでしょうか？
良い方法や、参照すべきプログラムのあるサイトなど（言語問わず）があれば教えて下さい。
どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

質問を拝読しました。  
おそらく初めてのプログラミングということで、開発環境の作成も含めて学習することが山のようにあると思います。頑張ってください。同じミスを繰り返さないためにも、作業ログを作成することをおすすめします。

開発環境ですが、特に問題ないと思います。
しかしmavenは学習するまで時間がかかるため、躓いたときは飛ばしてよいと思います。

> Tomcat 8.0 localhost
>   Jersey 2.0
>   Eclipse 4.4 Luna　PHPなどの入ったpackage

Eclipseを初めて使うのであれば、日本語に対応したPleiades All in Oneがおすすめです。
http://mergedoc.osdn.jp/index.html#/pleiades.html

> JAVA 　1.8
>   JDK 8
>   apache-maven-3.3.3
>   Jboss

REST対応のアプリケーションサーバを作ることが目的であるならば、まずはJerseyのチュートリアル解説を読んでください。そののちにプロトタイプ的な小さなソースを書くべきです。

XML/JSONを使用したアプリケーションサーバの解説のリンクを、コメントに投稿しました

Comment: [Jersey 1.19 User Guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/index.html)　　
[Chapter 4. XML Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/xml.html)　　
[Chapter 5. JSON Support](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/json.html)

Comment: コメントが遅くなって申し訳ありません、サイト大変参考にさせていただきました。本当にありがとうございます！時間が全くないのですが、急がば回れでこちらを見てクライアント側はまずできたのですが、肝心のwebサービス？側のjavaはこれからです。教えていただいたサイトプラス、Oracleの公式サイトを見てひとまず理解をし、今週中の提出になんとか間に合わせられるよう引き続き作業いたします。ご親切に、どうもありがとうございました。